# How to Write Query in Module in magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, reports

I have a query to take the report of product sale by SKU.

Can anyone let me know how can i write this query in a custom module to take report from magento report section?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are extensions available to turn any sql into reports.

One example:

https://github.com/kalenjordan/custom-reports

I have used this myself, and works great to turn sql to report.

Comment: i have download the extension but where i can run my query because it gives me only sample reports.

Answer (score 0):

You may use SKU's column in order grid(sales->order) to generate the report of order sale by product sku.

#### Display SKU in order grid.

[Reference Link](https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-sku-column-to-orders-grid/)

Comment: can you please let me know how can i do this?

Comment: I will send you link for download .